# Derivation of $\mathbb{E}\left [ S_{n}^2 \right ]$ in a simple random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, expected-value

Consider a simple random walk on the number line $\mathbb{Z}.$  At each unit, the walker moves left or right with probability $\frac{1}{2}.$  Assuming the walker starts at point $x$, we can define 
$$S_{n}=x+X_{1}+...+X_{n}$$
as the position of the walker at time $n.$   The increments $X_{1},X_{2}...$ are independent random variables with 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{j}=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_{j}=-1)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
My question is about the computation of $\mathbb{E}\left [ S_{n}^2 \right ].$  I am reading that 
$$\mathbb{E}\left [ S_{n}^2 \right ]= \mathbb{E}\left [ \left ( \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j} \right )^2 \right]=\mathbb{E}\left [ \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{j}X_{k} \right ]=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left [ X_{j}X_{k} \right ].$$
I understand that.  However, the author then writes 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left [ X_{j}X_{k} \right ]=n+\sum_{j\neq k}^{ } \mathbb{E}\left [ X_{j}X_{k} \right ].$$
I do not understand that derivation.  I know that there are four possibilities of $(X_{j},X_{k})$.  Mainly, 
$$(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),  \ \ \text{and} \ \ (-1,-1).$$
Can anyone explain this derivation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if $j=k$, then we have $X_j = X_k$, then $X_j X_k=X_j^2 = 1$.

Hence $$\sum_{j=1}^n X_j^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (1)=n$$

That is we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^n  \sum_{k=1}^n E[X_jX_k]=\sum_{j=1}^n   E[X_j^2]+ \sum_{j \ne k}   E[X_jX_k]= n + \sum_{j \ne k}   E[X_jX_k]$$

Comment: Exactly.  The author writes $j \neq k$, NOT $X_{j}\neq X_{k}$, which is your idea.  Surely if $j$ and $k$ are not equal, any possibility can arise.

Comment: It would make more sense to me if it was written as $$n+\sum_{X_{j}\neq X_{k}}^{ } \mathbb{E}\left [ X_{j}X_{k} \right ].$$

Comment: I have edited the post, see if that is clearer? if $j=k$, then we have $X_j=X_k$ for sure. If $j\ne k$, we are not sure, we leave it in that form for now.

Comment: I finally understand.  Thanks so much!